# Faster way to move a recordset (DAO or ADO) into a table

Tags: csv, ms-access, vba, recordset

I am new to StackOverflow, and not and expert coder. I have created a VBA sub to load a tab-separated file (160k records, about 20 columns) as a recordset (`Recordset.Open` method) within less then a second.

I then need to move it into a MS Access 2013 table for further processing with several queries. If I run a `DoCmd.Import` method into a table it takes about 1000 seconds (x2000 longer)

Is there any way to move all the records from the recordset into a table (existing or not) other then go through the entire recordset and append a record at a time?

Thanks

Comment: Admittedly, the `DoCmd.Import` method does more work than simply loading a csv into a recordset. The Access method needs to then append into a defined table schema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider directly querying the [text file](https://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile/) from an Access query where you query the folder that contains text file with a period qualifier on the file. This is a unique feature of the Jet/ACE SQL Engine (not compliant in other databases). You may need to create a `schema.ini` file in same directory as the tab-delimited file to properly define delimited format:

**Schema.ini** *(save in same folder as tab file; without this all data comes in one column)*

```
[myTabFile.txt]
ColNameHeader=True
CharacterSet=65001
Format=TabDelimited
```

**Append Query**

```
INSERT INTO myCurrentTable (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5)
SELECT t.Col1, t.Col2, t.Col3, t.Col4, t.Col5
FROM [text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;Database=C:\Path\To\Text\File].myTabFile.txt t;
```

**Make-Table Query**

```
SELECT t.Col1, t.Col2, t.Col3, t.Col4, t.Col5
INTO myNewTable
FROM [text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;Database=C:\Path\To\Text\File].myTabFile.txt t;
```

Comment: Haha...glad I could help!

Comment: @Parfait In a DB I'm testing, "insert into table (cols) select * from anotherTable" only inserts one row, while creating a new table with "select * into table from anotherTable" inserts all the rows. Why is that?